# Binary Search Algorithm Confusion

Tags: algorithm, search, binary

I've been reading some binary search algorithms I found on the internet, and I noticed this block of code within all examples I have encountered.

```
if (query > contents[midIndex])
{
    minIndex = midIndex + 1;
}
else if (query < contents[midIndex])
{
    maxIndex = midIndex - 1;
}
```

Why is that though? I tried doing this:

```
if (query > contents[midIndex])
{
    minIndex = midIndex;
    midIndex = (minIndex + maxIndex) / 2;
}
else if (query < contents[midIndex])
{
    maxIndex = midIndex;
    midIndex = (minIndex + maxIndex) / 2;
}
```

That code works in all the testing I've done, and isn't it faster? If it isn't faster, can someone explain the logic of the first snippet of code?

Comment: I expect you're doing the same thing as the examples (except you aren't eliminating the value at midIndex as you should be, hence their +- 1). Look for more code where the midIndex gets re-calculated for the next loop.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be faster?

Comment: sorry, misconception on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, all I can say is that, the first part is NOT binary search at all. (+ it doesn't even seem to recalculate the `midIndex` variable)

The purpose of binary searches is to be "focusing" the searches in "halves" of the total range until the spectrum has been narrowed down to the element we've been looking for...

Comment: http://academics.tjhsst.edu/compsci/CS2C/U2/bisearch.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Iterative
are wrong?

Comment: Nope; but you just forgot to mention the `int imid = (imin + imax) / 2;` part (I'm referring to the Wikipedia article) in the initial code you posted... it makes quite a difference, huh?

Comment: even then, isn't the +-1 unnecessary?

Comment: **Nope, it's not.** And here's why : let's say you start with the range (0..10). Is our `test_element` > `element[5]`? If yes then search to the "higher range"... but which one is that? (5..10)? or (6..10)? In a few words, there is no point in "rechecking" element[5], since we already know it's NOT the one we were looking for... (`test_element` was GREATER than `element[5]` right?) That's what we would do, even if it was LESS than... search in (0..4), and NOT in (0..5)... ;-)

Comment: yet another question, why are most of the conditions on the while loop (imax >= imin)? is the equal sign necessary?

Comment: The Equal sign in `while (imax >= imin)` is there to catch one single case : when there is one single element left (after narrowing our ranges several times) at position `imid` `= (imax=imin)`, which is the one we've been looking for... In all other cases, just "GREATER THAN" would suffice...

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can achieve binary search by loop or recursion and there are so many code
```

in the Internet.The principle of the binary search is like search one page in a book.The pages is orderd and you will look for one half every time.This is the principle of your first snippet of code.

```
 About the speed of the two segments,I think they are not whole.Binary search is
```

not so easy and there are some details should be noticed.Please google for it!